# firebase crashlytics data realtime API

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, crashlytics, fabric.io

I need app's Crashlytics data for further use, and need to pull all Crashlytics data in time.
How can I get Fabric or Firebase Crashlytics datas hourly?
Is there any api for this request?

Comment: Have you made any research on your own?

Comment: I have tried fabric api like browser and firebase use. It's not stable and I have caught by fabric team for using automatic script. And I try bigquery transfer service, which run delayed every time.

Comment: Why can't you use something like their Slack integration, and get pinged? Can you describe (in the question) what you actually need the data for?